# Youtube play video : The youtube account associated with this video has been terminated

Tags: ios, video, webview, youtube

I am playing video from playlist of my account. But some of videos are not playing with shows error in webview.

```
    - (void)playVideoWithId:(NSString *)videoId {

    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'768', height:'1024', videoId:'sLVGweQU7rQ', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, videoId];

    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    videoView.opaque = NO;
    //videoView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];

    videoView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

    [videoView loadHTMLString:youTubeVideoHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
}
```

**Error image**

[image]

How can I fix this.

Comment: You might want to replace `videoId:'sLVGweQU7rQ'` with `videoId:'%@'` in `youTubeVideoHTML`. This way the parameter will be correctly used in the HTML string. I think that will make everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When an account is terminated or closed, all videos uploaded by the account will be removed from youtube server. You can't view this video.